# Mockito exception on class cast

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I had mocked Jsch() class and getting class cast exception in the method below.

Original method.

```
JSch jsch = getSftpJsch();
session = jsch.getSession(sessionObj);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
LOGGER.info("sfg channel opened and connected.");
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
channelSftp.cd(inboundPath);
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channelSftp.ls(filePattern);
```

Getting Mockito exception on line.

```
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
```

Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MockitoMock$1983492043 cannot be cast to com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp

Test case calling method.

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)
private JSch mockJsch;

private AppUtils sftp = new AppUtils(){
    @Override
    JSch getSftpJsch() {
        return mockJsch;
    }
};

@Test
public void tetsGetFileList(){
    sftp.getFileList(folderPath, fileName, charEncoding);
}
```

Comment: What type is `session` and what type is the return value defined for the `session.openChannel()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)` takes care of creating a mock for every call. Including `channel = session.openChannel("sftp");`.

So `channel` now contains some mocked subtype of the `Channel` base class. That is why the cast fails.

So the slightly longer way to mock this would be:

```
@Mock
private JSch mockJsch;

@Mock
private Session session;

@Mock
private ChannelSftp channel;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Mockito.when(mockJsch.getSession(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(session);
    Mockito.when(session.openChannel(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(channel);
}

private AppUtils sftp = new AppUtils(){
    @Override
    JSch getSftpJsch() {
        return mockJsch;
    }
};

@Test
public void tetsGetFileList(){
    sftp.getFileList(folderPath, fileName, charEncoding);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michiel I will add these.